# Borders Positions

Tags: html, css, html-table

CSS:

```
table.tftable {
       font-size:12px;
       color:#333333;
       width:50%;
       border-width: 1px;
       border-color: #729ea5;
       border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.tftable th {
       font-size:12px;
       background-color:#acc8cc;
       border-width: 1px;
       padding: 8px;
       border-style: solid;
       border-color: #729ea5;
       text-align:left;
}
table.tftable tr {
       background-color:#d4e3e5;
}
table.tftable td {
       font-size:12px;
       border-width: 1px;
       padding: 8px;
       border-style: solid;
       border-color: #729ea5;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $queryOtherEvents = "select * from `eventos` where `data` > '$data'";
  $resultOtherEvents = mysql_query($queryOtherEvents);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultOtherEvents)) {
    $nome = $row['nome'];
    $data = $row['data'];
    $url = $row['descricao'];
    echo "<table id=tfhover class=tftable border=1>";
    echo "<tr><th>$data</th><th><a href=$url>$nome</a></th></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
  }
?>
```

Im showing a date of an event and the name of event in table, but if the name of event is bigger than 1st, position of borders switch..., how you can see in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Remove all the widths and specify a width in pixels for the th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you are inserting one table for each row.
You should use one table and for each row in your database add one row to the table.

try this

```
   <?php
      $queryOtherEvents = "select * from `eventos` where `data` > '$data'";
      $resultOtherEvents = mysql_query($queryOtherEvents);
     echo "<table id=tfhover class=tftable border=1>";
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultOtherEvents)) {
        $nome = $row['nome'];
        $data = $row['data'];
        $url = $row['descricao'];

        echo "<tr><th>$data</th><th><a href=$url>$nome</a></th></tr>";

      }
     echo "</table>";

?>
```